# Angular 7 modal dialog/popup from service

Tags: angular, dialog, modal-dialog, popup

I am new to Angular, and have a question regarding services.  In the past in other languages, I would create components that were self contained that could be called from anywhere in the application.

I have a need for popup dialog and error messages shown modally that can be called from either a different service or from the ts file for a component.

My ultimate goal is to not have the HTML for the dialog in multiple components, but rather in a single service or component & service.

My initial thoughts are something along the lines of a service with a template and style section (if these are available in a service) that is fully self contained or if this is not doable, then a service with the methods for the dialog and a separate component containing the markup and styles.

What I am thinking is one of 2 ideas:
1.  A service that has the necessary html, styles and methods to display the dialog or error message
2.  A service and component that works together to show the dialog

Am I going down the correct road with this train of thought or am I thinking about doing something that will bite me?

Comment: Use Angular Material MatDialog you can extend it and use it as a service between your other components you can find more example on their site. https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Answer (score 3):

Using a Service to encapsulate Angular dialog logic is a good approach. Leveraging [Angular Material Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview), you could create a service as follows.

## DialogService

```js
import { ElementRef, Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material'
    
import { DialogProfileOptionsComponent } from './dialog-profile-options/dialog-profile-options.component'
import { DialogYesNoComponent } from './dialog-yes-no/dialog-yes-no.component'
    
    
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DialogService {
    
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }
    
  public open_info_dialog() { }
    
  public open_profile_options_dialog(
    { 
      position_relative_to_element, 
      user,
      has_backdrop = false, 
      height = '135px', 
      width = '290px' 
    }: {
      position_relative_to_element: ElementRef, 
      user: firebase.User, 
      has_backdrop?: boolean,
      height?: string, 
      width?: string
    }
  ): MatDialogRef<DialogProfileOptionsComponent> {
    const dialog_ref: MatDialogRef<DialogProfileOptionsComponent> =
      this.dialog.open(DialogProfileOptionsComponent, {
        hasBackdrop: has_backdrop,
        height: height,
        width: width,
        data: { position_relative_to_element: position_relative_to_element, user: user }
      });
    return dialog_ref;
  }
    
  public open_yes_no_dialog(
    { 
      question, 
      title = 'Confirm', 
      yes_button_first = true,
      has_backdrop = false, 
      height = '250px', 
      width = '350px' 
    }: {
      question: string, 
      title?: string, 
      yes_button_first?: boolean, 
      has_backdrop?: boolean,
      height?: string, width?: string
    }
  ): MatDialogRef<DialogYesNoComponent> {  
    const dialog_ref = this.dialog.open(DialogYesNoComponent, {
      autoFocus: true,
      backdropClass: 'cdk-overlay-transparent-backdrop',
      closeOnNavigation: true,
      disableClose: false,
      hasBackdrop: has_backdrop,
      height: height,
      width: width,
      data: { question: question, title: title, yes_button_first: yes_button_first }
    });
    
    return dialog_ref;
  }
    
  open_warning_dialog() { /* TODO  */ }
}
```

## dialog-profile-options.component.ts

```js
import { Component, ElementRef, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { MatDialogConfig, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog'
    
    
@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-profile-options',
  templateUrl: './dialog-profile-options.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-profile-options.component.css']
})
export class DialogProfileOptionsComponent implements OnInit {
  private position_relative_to_element: ElementRef
    
  constructor(
    public dialog_ref: MatDialogRef<DialogProfileOptionsComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public options: { 
      position_relative_to_element: ElementRef,
      user: firebase.User 
    }
  ) {  
    this.position_relative_to_element = options.position_relative_to_element
  }
    
  ngOnInit() {
    const mat_dialog_config = new MatDialogConfig()
    const rect: DOMRect = this.position_relative_to_element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()
    
    mat_dialog_config.position = { right: `10px`, top: `${rect.bottom + 2}px` }
    this.dialog_ref.updatePosition(mat_dialog_config.position)
  }
    
}
```

## dialog-profile-options.component.html

```html
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <div><b>{{options.user.displayName}}</b></div>
  <div class="text-secondary">{{options.user.email}}</div>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close="view-profile" cdkFocusInitial>View profile</button>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close="sign-out">Sign out</button>
</div>
```

Comment: @Christoper, thanks, I am trying to avoid any additional dependencies like PrimeNG or Material, but I think I can take what you posted and make it work with an html/css template and service.